# Shopify adds &nbsp to article.content

Tags: shopify, liquid

Pretty disappointed with the Shopify blog editor. Just wondering why my blog post is stretched out across the page. Turns out Shopify puts in `&nbsp` characters instead of actual whitespace.

What's the ideal way to remove this?

Comment: I haven't seen that happen before. Do you have an example blog post you can point us to?

Comment: Here's a screenshot. https://postimg.org/image/47gg3g7xj/

Answer (score 0):

It is a Unicode non-breaking space character. It adds when you copy and paste the content. Find two words with an &nbsp between them. Delete that space and Add space with your keyboard where that space was.
Save. The &nbsp character would remove.